# How to capture location coordinates without having GPS receiver Chip?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to capture location coordinates for the device which does not have gps receiver chip(or for the device whose gps receiver chip is damaged). Does android provide any API to achieve this. Does A-GPS also refers the same location api?

Comment: You should remove the "GPS" in "GPS location".- So you want location coordinates without having a GPS receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Use NETWORK PROVIDER instead of GPS for some options